# JAX-RS, components can access which information through the request life cycle

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

While going through the processing of a request in JAX-RS, what I studied is that the flow of the whole process is as below;

[image]

I know that there are different components , which serve the purpose of pluggability, like we can have filters and can plug them to whatever resource methods
we want, same is the case with interceptors(and I know that they are triggered around MessageBodyWriters and MessageBodyReaders). But I am confused about each of the component
and the piece of information which each component can access while the request is passing through them,

The crux which I Learned is that:

---

### Filters

Can modify(or should deal with ) headers only. However I have seen a method getEntityStream in the ContainerRequestContext of filter. Which stream this method is referring too?

[image]

---

### Interceptors

Well the only example I had was zipping the stream into some GzipReader(or something like that) over the internet . Is it the only utilisation of the Interceptor? And I suspect that the whole request body is available in the interceptor, see the image below.

[image]

---

### MessageBodyReader/Writers

They are understandable, and I guess they have the same level of request information as available to that of the Interceptors.

---

### Question:

I have not understood that what things each component can access from the incoming request, and what should be modified in each of the components, well this question may be broad , but dedicated
link pointing to solution of the queries may be helpful.

### Edit:

Just tested. Filter can access the message body and can modify it, So do the interceptor. ://

Comment: well different frameworks provide you the phase in which you want your interceptor/filter to be invoked. That phase specifies what all information you can access in your code. This is how I have worked with Apache CXF, can't say if there is a standard somewhere.

Comment: @Sikorski Thanks for your response, if there are no standards then there must be some conventions :).

Comment: as i said each framework will have its own convention, you can check the CXF's here : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with Filters:

**FILTERS:**

Filters can modify inbound and outbound requests and responses including *modification of headers*, *entity* and *other request/response parameters*.

Further Filters are classified as **Container/Server Filters** and **Client Filters**.

Consider Server filters: There are further two obvious types:

- *request filter*
- *response filter*

There two main differences between these two types(depending on what they access):

1. **Response filters** implement **ContainerResponseFilter** interface and has two arguments:

*container request*`(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)`   and

*container response*`(ContainerResponseContext responseContext)`.

Now what are the things these two arguments access:

`public interface ContainerRequestContext`

*Container request filter context. A mutable class that provides request-specific information for the filter, such as request URI, message headers, message entity or request-scoped properties. The exposed setters allow modification of the exposed request-specific information.*

`public interface ContainerResponseContext`

*Container response filter context. A mutable class that provides response-specific information for the filter, such as message headers, message entity or request-scoped properties. The exposed setters allow modification of the exposed response-specific information.*

Notice that requestContext can access one additional thing: *requestURI*

2. **Request filters** implements **ContainerRequestFilter** and has only one argument:

container request`(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)`

---

Coming to your question:

**Which stream is referred in the method setEntityStream(arg0) and getEntityStream()?**

This can be broken down as:

- **getEntityStream():**
  *Request entity stream on the server side is where an entity is read from the client request and response entity stream on the client side
  is where an entity is read from the server response.*
- **setEntityStream(arg0):** On the server means when writing out a response entity and on the client side writing request entity for a
  request to be sent out to the server.**

**EDIT:**

1. Filters can be used to verify certain criteria for any request. If the criteria is not met, filters can also abort the response.

Consider the following example from [jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html):

```
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                throws IOException {

    final SecurityContext securityContext =
                requestContext.getSecurityContext();
    if (securityContext == null ||
                !securityContext.isUserInRole("privileged")) {

            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity("User cannot access the resource.")
                .build());
        }
    }
}
```

The AuthorizationRequestFilter in the example checks whether the authenticated user is in the privileged role. When the filter method is finished the response passed as a parameter to the abortWith method is used to respond to the request. Response filters, if any are registered, will be executed and will have possibility to process the aborted response.

2. Filters can influence which method will be matched. **Pre-matching filters** are request filters that are executed before the request matching is started.

   ```
   @PreMatching
   public class PreMatchingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                   throws IOException {
       // change all PUT methods to POST
       if (requestContext.getMethod().equals("PUT")) {
           requestContext.setMethod("POST");
       }
     }
   }
   ```

The *PreMatchingFilter* is a simple pre-matching filter which changes all PUT HTTP methods to POST. This might be useful when you want to always handle these PUT and POST HTTP methods with the same Java code.

---

**INTERCEPTORS:**

*Write-Interceptors* wraps the entity into *GZIPOutput stream* and *Reader-Interceptor* wraps the entity into *GZIPInput stream* which decompresses the data from the compressed entity received.

IN ADDITION, Interceptors can also be used to provide **Digital Signatures**. For Digital Signatures, a *hash of the body* needs to be calculated and added to the Signature request (client-side) or response (server-side) header.

Comment: That was helpful Dhaval, however I can see  that filters can do the same what an interceptor can do, and both are pluggable components. What is the difference then? Can I add **Digital signatures** in filters?

Comment: maybe we can think interceptors as decorating the request/response in some way whereas filter would just act as a barrier. Is this correct ?

Comment: @nobalG Provided edits in my answer to describe how Filters differ from Interceptors. Answer to your second question: I do not think we can add **Digital Signatures** in filters as filters cannot provide hashing or encode the entities. It can manipulate headers but that won't serve the purpose of Digital Signatures.

Comment: @nobalG What do you mean by _digital signatures_?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin It is something depicted by the answerer in the answer(see the last paragraph in the above answer), According to the answerer this is what is making the difference b/w interceptors and filters, I found the whole answer helpful except this 'signature' part.

Comment: @nobalG Oh! Sorry, I've missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html) is a good start point to learn more about the JAX-RS API:

### JAX-RS Filters

Have a look at what the documentation says about [filters](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9738):

> Filters can be used when you want to modify any request or response parameters like headers. For example you would like to add a response header `X-Powered-By` to each generated response. Instead of adding this header in each resource method you would use a response filter to add this header.
>
> There are filters on the server side and the client side.
>
> Server filters:
>
> - [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html)
> - [`ContainerResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html)
>
> Client filters:
>
> - [`ClientRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html)
> - [`ClientResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseFilter.html)

According to the filter, you are provided with the request/response context objects that allows you to modify the requested method, the requested URI, the headers, the response status code, etc. And you also can access a stream that allows you to manipulate the request/response payload.

While [`ContainerRequestContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) and [`ContainerResponseContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html) are available on server, [`ClientRequestContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestContext.html) and [`ClientResponseContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseContext.html) are available on client.

### JAX-RS Interceptors

Have a look at what the documentation says about [interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9907):

> Interceptors share a common API for the server and the client side. Whereas filters are primarily intended to manipulate request and response parameters like HTTP headers, URIs and/or HTTP methods, interceptors are intended to manipulate entities, via manipulating entity input/output streams. If you for example need to encode entity body of a client request then you could implement an interceptor to do the work for you.
>
> There are two kinds of interceptors, [`ReaderInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) and [`WriterInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html).
>
> Reader interceptors are used to manipulate inbound entity streams. These are the streams coming from the "wire". So, using a reader interceptor you can manipulate request entity stream on the server side (where an entity is read from the client request) and response entity stream on the client side (where an entity is read from the server response).
>
> Writer interceptors are used for cases where entity is written to the "wire" which on the server means when writing out a response entity and on the client side when writing request entity for a request to be sent out to the server.
>
> Writer and reader interceptors are executed before message body readers or writers are executed and their primary intention is to wrap the entity streams that will be used in message body reader and writers.
>
> [...]

In the interceptors, you are provided with context objects so you can access the request/response payload streams. Additonaly, you can access a mutable map that allows you to manipulate the request/response headers.

[`ReaderInterceptorContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptorContext.html) and [`WriterInterceptorContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptorContext.html) are available both on client and on server.

Comment: Both of them can access and manipulate same piece of information though. Am I right?

Comment: @nobalG Both filter and interceptor APIs allow you to manipulate the payload and headers. However, the filters are intended to manipulate headers and the interceptors are intended to manipulate the payload.

Comment: @nobalG Let me know if you need any further clarification.